# Encoding difficulties: &amp;#163; displaying instead of £

Tags: asp.net, html, character-encoding

I am accessing data from an SQL Server database to my ASP.Net C# based website. This data is received from affiliate companies and contains `&amp;#163;`  for the £ sign. But when I display this data inside a label, instead of `£` it shows `&#163;`.

Note: The `&amp;` is converted to `&`.

I know it's a character encoding problem and I've tried to provide the character encoding as 'utf-8' and also 'ISO-8859-1' in the header.

Which character encoding should I use to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a problem with finding the correct character encoding to turn the bytes into text, it's how the text has been encoded (or rather escaped).

The problem is that the text has been HTML encoded twice. The first time it turns the `£` into `&#163;`, the second time into `&amp;#163;`.

So, to correct this you have to use the `HtmlDecode` method to reverse the second step.

Comment: But, the label which is displaying the data is in the item template of a gridview:

                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Gift") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>

so how can I put HtmlDecode function there?
Sorry for asking novice questions I am just a beginner.

Comment: You can't bind the property if you want to change the value before displaying it, use `Eval` instead: `Text='<%# HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Eval("Gift")) %>'`

Comment: That was giving the error of invalid arguments for HtmlDecode, so tried this:

Text='<%# HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Eval("Gift").ToString()) %>'

And it worked like a charm, but all thanks to you for providing me the right direction. Really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 2):

&amp;#163 **should** render as &#163.  By using the &amp; you've escaped the HTML escape code.

Comment: probably yes, that's the case, but do I have a solution to solve the problem? :\

I surely cant change the data in the table, so I would have to find a solution at the application end.

Comment: It sounds like it's been HTML-encoded twice.  Therefore, perhaps you can just HTML-decode it twice?  (HttpUtility.HtmlDecode)

Comment: But the label is in the itemtemplate of a gridview, here it goes:

<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Gift") %>'> </asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>

So how can i apply htmldecode to it? :/

Comment: Lots of ways.  Remember that what sits between the <%# and %> tags is just C#.  So, you could have: Text='<%# HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Bind("Gift")) %>'

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be encoded twice and decoded only once. What was the step it goes through ?